# Create loop in Javascript to use with imap-simple nodejs package

Tags: javascript, loops, setinterval, nightwatch.js

Firstly, some background as to what my test script will cover.

Pressing a button on a website will fire off an email to a test mailbox.

This email can take anything between 10 and 30 minutes to arrive in the test mailbox.

So using the following code from [imap-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap-simple) ;

```
'get new email info': function(browser) {
    imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
        return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
            var searchCriteria = ['UNSEEN'];
            var fetchOptions = {
                bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'],
                markSeen: false
            };
            return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (results) {
                var subjects = results.map(function (res) {
                    return res.parts.filter(function (part) {
                        return part.which === 'HEADER';
                        })[0].body.subject[0];
                });
            console.log(subjects);
```

Correctly comes back with a blank **subjects** array, as the email hasn't been received by the test mailbox yet.

Adding a 30 minutes pause to the beginning of the script 'works', as after the 30 minutes the **subjects** array is populated as the email is (99.99% of the time) sent within a 30 minute window.

However, it is definitely far from ideal as the email might be received within 15 minutes, meaning the test is 'wasting' 15 minutes.

So what I'd ideally like to do is write some form of loop (?) that tests if the **subjects** array is populated or not.

So if the array is populated, carry on with the rest of the test script (which entails testing that the array contains a certain text).

If the array is not populated, wait for another minute before trying again.

Continue this trying every minute until the array is populated.

I've tried **setInterval**, **For** loops, **While** loops, etc but I can't seem to get them to work and I'm out of ideas to be honest.

Any advice, help, references would be greatly appreciated and any more info can be promptly added if required.

Comment: setInterval seems the right choice here

Comment: You should have a look at Promise ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise ) combined with interval.
so return a promise, and resolve it in your interval when your condition is met.

Comment: you can have some retrying promise policy, like this one https://gist.github.com/briancavalier/842626/c0eb8816486a95d907ca1cd754c9f6e17f68d589

Comment: What's your test environment? Node version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that could be using recursion.

```
const createPromise = ms => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms)
    });
    
function findUnseenEmails(connection) {
    return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
        var searchCriteria = [
            'UNSEEN'
        ];
    
        var fetchOptions = {
             bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'],
             markSeen: false
        };
    
        return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (results) {
            var subjects = results.map(function (res) {
                return res.parts.filter(function (part) {
                    return part.which === 'HEADER';
                })[0].body.subject[0];
            });
            console.log(subjects);
            return subjects.length > 0 ? subjects : createPromise(5000).then(function() { return findUnseenEmails(connection)});
      });
  });
}

imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
      return findUnseenEmails(connection);
    }).then((subjects) => console.log('finished', subjects));
```

Of course there is a possibility and danger of stack overflow, but in such scenario feel free to come back to stack overflow to find here with the help of our community non-recursive solution.

Result:

[image: Gif with result]

**EDIT:**
Answering your question regarding closing connection: 
I'd do it like this (in *findUnseenEmails* function)

```
if (subjects.length > 0) {
    connection.end();
    return subjects;
} else {
    return createPromise(5000).then(function() { return findUnseenEmails(connection)});
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the info @matvs, I'll give this a go.  Just one more thing, I also need to add a test to ensure that the output (of **subjects**) is correct. I currently have `assert.deepEqual(subjects, 'MCN - New enquiry for your bike listing (ref: 1234567)')` within my existing script, but where and how would I implement this assertion within the recursion script you kindly supplied? Thanks

Comment: I guess you can put assertion in last 'then' handler, i.e. .then((subjects) => console.log('finished', subjects))

Comment: Note also that subjects is an array, I am not sure how it goes with using deepEqual with a string and an array.

Comment: Sorry @matvs , just one more thing on this. The recursion you specified worked as I wanted it. The only think I've now found is that the recursion doesn't end the connection within imap, so this is always open. I've tried to find where the imap-simple `connection.end()` command should be added, but wherever I put it, it doesn't appear to work. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: I've added a snippet with a solution for the problem with connection.end(). Let me know if it works :)

Comment: That works perfectly, you're a star @matvs ! Many thanks for you help in this, it's very much appreciated.